# MySQL: how to get the list of tables using ODBC

Tags: mysql, odbc

I am connecting to a MySQL DB trough a terminal who only have a program with an ODBC connection to a MySQL DB. I can put querys in the program, but not access MySQL directly.

I there a way to query the DB to obtain the list of tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a SQL query:

```
Show tables;
```

You should be able to execute that query.