# Find out what tables are in a MySQL Db

Tags: mysql

Is there a query that will return all the names of the tables inside a mySQL database?

Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone google before posting on here anymore? /sarcasm

Comment: I tried a google but I couldn't seem to find anything, my google fu is off this morning

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: how to get the list of tables using ODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308809/mysql-how-to-get-the-list-of-tables-using-odbc)

Comment: You get solutions faster than you could using google :)

Comment: How about searching stackoverflow first at least?

Comment: fyi google "mysql show all tables" had the answer in the second link. Same with "mysql all tables"

Comment: This question is now #4 for the search term [Is there a query that will return all the names of the tables inside a mySQL database?](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Is+there+a+query+that+will+return+all+the+names+of+the+tables+inside+a+mySQL+database%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a) so will help future googlers!

Comment: Martin: it is in your Google :P

Comment: @Sarfraz that's not the point of stackoverflow. Getting an answer to a trivial question by posting on stack first is a waste of everyones time and you arguably don't learn a thing by having the answer given to you.

Comment: @Matt Phillips: I didn't like this basic question here too and I totally agree with you. I have seen some users becoming really lazy and even dependent on others and they come up with questions even trivial ones. That should not happen for sure, this keeps them from learning and exploring on their own.

Comment: Well I did learn something, I learnt how to show all tables of a mysql db

Comment: @Matt - The point of SO is to provide a comprehensive high quality peer reviewed knowledge resource in one place. Easily google-able questions are not discouraged (though duplicates are albeit somewhat ambivalently).

Comment: I truly apologize to all who were personally offended by my question

Comment: @Martin. I agree completely. Thats why Phrogz comment is good because even searching mysql show all tables on SO gives several previous questions about the same thing. I was trying to point out the lack of due diligence in just asking a simple question versus trying to find an answer first whether its on google or SO. You would think that's common sense but its obviously not to a large proportion of people.

Comment: @Pete it's all good. I think I was just being sarcastic and it turned into a bit more than that!

Comment: FYI I voted to close it since I can't delete it

Comment: @Pete: I don't think anyone was personally offended by this question. The point is, it is something you could really easily find by googling. I've ansewred the exact same question several times already on different Q&A sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `show tables;`, you can access the information via an actual query against [`TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html) table which holds the info:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
show tables;
```

Does what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something more versatile than SHOW TABLES; use

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME 
  /*add some more columns if you need them*/ 
  /* add some aggregating functions!*/
FROM 
  information_schema.TABLES 
/* join some more tables! it's fun! */
WHERE 
  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourDatabaseName'
  /*add your own conditions!*/
  /* order, group, limit! */
```